# The font-size is not changing on the update of browser font size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used em and rem based sizes in my page to make it scale based on the browser font size. However when I change browser font, nothing really happens.
When I inspected the computed values of sizes it turns out that it always refers **1em** to **10px** no matter what browser font size is. I am using Bootstrap and it sets the base font size to 62.5% of the browser font size which is **10px**. But when the browser font size is increased it should be increased too. My code is give below:

image.html

```
<div id="img-container" class="container-fluid" (mouseenter)="displayNav(true)" (mouseleave)="displayNav(false)">
    <div class="row image-header">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h5>Image</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row image-body">
        <div id="img-prev" class="col-2" [ngClass]="{'invisible': !navigationVisible}">
            <button id="btn-prev" (click)="loadImage('prev')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-3"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div id="img-box" class="col-8">
            <img id="main-img" [src]="imgUrl" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"/>
        </div>
        <div id="img-next" class="col-2" [ngClass]="{'invisible': !navigationVisible}">
            <button id="btn-prev" (click)="loadImage('next')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-3"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-1 image-footer">
        <div class="col-12 image-meta">
            <span class="like-button margin-2" *ngIf="!like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3 margin-2 hover-link" (click)="likeImg()"></i>Like</span>
            <span class="like-button margin-2" *ngIf="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-3 margin-2 hover-link" (click)="likeImg()"></i>Unike</span>
            <span class="margin-2">{{likeCount}} liked this</span> 
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

image.css

```
#main-img {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0em auto;
}

#img-box {
    text-align: center; 
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0em;
}

#img-container {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin:  0em;
    padding: 0em;
    height: 100%;
}

#img-prev {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

#img-next {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.justify-content-flex-end {
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.like-button {
    color: blue;
}

.margin-1 {
    margin: 0.125em;
}

.margin-2 {
    margin: 0.125em;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.hover-link:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.align-items-center {
    align-content: center;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.image-header {
    height: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-body {
    height: 85%;
    max-height: 85%;
    position: relative;
}

.image-footer {
    margin-top: 0.625em; 
    height: 10%;
}

.image-meta {
    margin: 0em auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the base font-size on your `body` element.

```
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`em` and `rem` font-sizes are relative to element parent (em) and `html` font-size (rem). In some Bootstrap templates`html` and `body` font-size is set in pixels by default. So you have to change it to relative values if you want it to respect browser font-size.

```
html {font-size: 1.6em}
body {font-size: 1.4em}
```

And make sure your custom css file comes after others, to override their values

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
font-size=anyvalue!important:
}
```

Just add !important to the value

Answer (score 0):

Once I upgraded to Bootstrap 4 from Bootstrap 3 the issue got resolved. It is now responding to different browser font size settings.